# No event invites in the iCloud calendar

Tags: icloud, email, calendar, ical

I'm trying to migrate my custom domain email from Zoho to iCloud+ and everything went smoothly (in terms of mail) until I got stuck with the calendar. I don't get event invites (only notifications in the email) in the calendar macOS/iOS app at all for mynamemail@icloud.com, myaliasmail@icloud.com, mail@mydomain.com

It feels like it should work out of the box, but it doesn't.

I also found the same kind of questions (but not so many to suspect that everybody has it), but no answers:

- [Calendar invitations don’t appear in the Calendar Inbox - iCloud problem?](https://talk.macpowerusers.com/t/calendar-invitations-dont-appear-in-the-calendar-inbox-icloud-problem/19094)(MacPowerUsers.com)
- [Custom email domain & calendar invitations](https://www.reddit.com/r/iCloud/comments/108fqdg/custom_email_domain_calendar_invitations/)(Reddit)

I'm not sure a reboot helps because it's happening on both the phone and the laptop simultaneously.

Extra note: I downloaded custom calendar, added iCloud CalDav there and it doesn't sync too. Feels like it's iCloud's issue

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already rebooted your devices and the issue persists, it might be related to iCloud's configuration or settings. Personally, I haven't come across your issue, but you could try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Verify that your custom domain is correctly set up with iCloud. You can refer to Zoho's documentation on [how to verify](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/domain-verification.html) and [set up a domain](https://www.zoho.com/mail/how-to/setup-my-domain-with-zoho-mail.html) with Zoho Mail. Additionally, iCloud's support page ([in this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253163359)) on setting up a custom domain for email and calendars might also be helpful.
2. Check if your iCloud calendar settings are correct. Make sure that you have enabled the option to receive event invitations in your iCloud calendar settings. You can refer to Apple's support page on [how to change iCloud Calendar settings](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/icloud/mme4d73a8727/icloud).
3. Try removing and re-adding your custom domain email account in the calendar macOS/iOS app. You can refer to the [steps provided by a Reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/iCloud/comments/ptukvk/added_custom_domain_email_to_outlook_app/) on how to add a custom domain email to Outlook since the process is similar in the calendar app.
4. Try creating a new test event and inviting your custom domain email address to it. Check if you receive the invite and if it appears in your calendar app.
5. If the issue persists, you can contact Apple Support for further assistance.

I hope these steps help resolve your issue with the iCloud calendar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have a scheduled call with apple support. Hope it helps and if it helps, I'll publish it here

Comment: Cool, yes, please let me know.

Comment: @AntonShkurenko Did you ever find out from Support why it didn't work, or more importantly, did they let you know how to solve the issue?

Comment: Nope, they didn't tell. One guy mailed me, he had similar issue and he also approached apple support but also without any help :(